# WordPress show field in admin section by getting data from Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this plugin to create Custom Post Types: https://wp-types.com/documentation/

I have created a new post type called "Sponsors".

What I want to achieve now is to create a custom field inside the "Article" section that will let the admin select one or more sponsors created through the custom post type. So the admin will be able to link a sponsor to a specific article.

How do I retrieve the data of the "Sponsors" custom post type and show the contents inside a dropdown when creating an article?

Is there a way in PHP or using the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT ID,post_title FROM $wpdb->posts 
     WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_type = 'portfolio'
    ORDER BY post_date DESC";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);



$out = '<select  name="porfolio">';
 foreach ($pageposts as $post) {

    $out.= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >'.$post->post_title.'</option>';
    # code...
 }
 $out.= '</select>';

 echo $out;
```